# Manipulate Javascript RegExp occurrences in string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm converting phone numbers into a clickable url. I have an html string with random phone numbers appearing in a non particular/consistent way:

> Fidel Velazquez (834)316-90-90
>  ↵Libertad (834) 316-2930
>  ↵

I'm using regex in order to search the occurrences and "linkify" them, this is the function that helps with that:

```
    var regex = new RegExp(
        "\\+?\\(?\\d*\\)? ?\\(?\\d+\\)?\\d*([\\s./-]?\\d{2,})+",
        "g"
    );
    return inputText.replace(regex, '<a href="tel:$&">$&</a>');
```

The problem is, that for the example above, I'm getting a white space before the phone number, and that is preventing the html link from working correctly (i.e I'm getting " (834)316-90-90" instead of "(834)316-90-90").

Is there something I can change directly on my regex? Or is there a way to apply a .replace(' ', ''); only to the occurrences?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a function for replacement, allowing you to customise the replacement string.

```js
var inputText = `Fidel Velazquez (834)316-90-90
Libertad (834) 316-2930
`;

var regex = new RegExp(
  "\\+?\\(?\\d*\\)? ?\\(?\\d+\\)?\\d*([\\s./-]?\\d{2,})+",
  "g"
);
var output = inputText.replace(regex, function(m) {
  var match = m.replace(/ /g, '');
  return `<a href="tel:${match}">${m}</a>`;
});

console.log(output);
```

Or you can construct a more careful regular expression, taking the original apart, and putting it together in a different way, using capture groups. This is more restricted, but sufficient for what you described. (Also, `new RegExp` is not idiomatic, you'd only use it when you have dynamically generated regular expression.)

For your specific trouble, you could even require the space to be matched only when the previous thing matches... Many different solutions, depending exactly what your requirement is. Note that this regular expression will also match some things that do not look like phone numbers: